# Default All Documents view in a SharePoint document library got corrupted

Tags: sharepoint-online, view

Some how the default view (All Documents - .../Forms/AllItems.aspx) in a document library in SharePoint Online got corrupted and now shows gibberish:

"...PK!A�.fT[Content_Types].xml �(����n�0E����� �tQUUH},�HM?����/����;@��(�I6H0s�=xF��V� |���d� H�[!M����[�H��LY9�B ����h�uT���E�����YȬ���z�"���:�X �~0x�ܚ&��� ��l�b��� ɷ��$�Mc���+��@�j<�p�a�)�Y�:]q@��2T�=a!]�Æ������}���R@2e>�3�]tm����Fev���- ɡ�Wn�[!�w�*k+�I����q� \���폇Qp ��s/��W��c�R`��\��"...

As a temporary solution I created a new default view, but need to restore the old one at AllItems.aspx as users have links to it...

What is the best way to restore or repair the view?
Shall I delete the view and recreate new with the same AllItems.aspx address?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Is this the classic view or the modern view having this issue?

Try removing the document library web part from the `AllItems.aspx` in classic experience and then re-add it again.

The solution you come up with is also workable. You can delete the default list view and then change the URL of another list view to "AllItems" under **Web address of this view**.

Comment: Thank you - I have implemented my solution and it worked OK.
Best

Comment: I deleted AllItems.aspx and recreated it after that and it worked OK.
Thanks to all who looked in my problem and Chelsea_MSFT for providing alternatives.
Best